# pyqt5.6 interceptRequest doesn't work

Tags: qt, interceptor, pyqt5, qwebpage

I want to interceptor a url request to another by subclass QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor:

```
class RequestInterceptor(QWebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor): 
    def interceptRequest(self,info): 
        print('#################interceptRequest')
        print(info.requestUrl(),info.firstPartyUrl(),info.NavigationType,info.resourceType(),info.requestMethod())
        if info.requestUrl().endswith("/jquery.js"):
           info.redirect('/jqueryTest.js')



app = QApplication([]) 
p = QWebEnginePage() 
v = QWebEngineView() 
v.setPage(p) 
p.profile().setRequestInterceptor(RequestInterceptor())
c.registerObject('bridge', p)
url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.html?t=5"
v.setUrl(QUrl(url)) 
v.show() 
app.exec_()
```

When I run the code,the interceptor does not work!
Hope someone give me help,thanks!

PS:
May It is caused by python garbage collection。So I store the interceptor in varible by modifying the code

```
p.profile().setRequestInterceptor(RequestInterceptor())
```

to

```
interceptor = RequestInterceptor()
p.profile().setRequestInterceptor(interceptor )
```

That's All.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean precisely? Did your proposed change help?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is caused by python garbage collection. So I store the interceptor in a variable by modifying the code:

```
p.profile().setRequestInterceptor(RequestInterceptor())
```

to:

```
interceptor = RequestInterceptor()
p.profile().setRequestInterceptor(interceptor )
```

That's All.

Comment: It's an issue related to Python, more discussion here
http://pyqt.riverbankcomputing.narkive.com/N9NK1wyq/qwebengineurlrequestinterceptor-doesn-t-work

Comment: The issue seems to be still present in PyQt 5.10. I wondered why my own attempts did fail, but you gave the correct solution: ensure that the request interceptor doesn't get garbage collected too early.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as an attribute to the window object worked for me, indeed probably some garbage collection issue like mentioned here. The other solution here doesn't work for me.

```
self.interceptor = WebEngineUrlRequestInterceptor()
profile = QWebEngineProfile().defaultProfile()
profile.setUrlRequestInterceptor(self.interceptor)
```